# How to access the secrets, keys from azure keyvault in app-configmap.yaml file

Tags: azure-aks, azure-keyvault

I have created AKS based application deployment where all the environment variables of application are defined in app-configmap.yaml file. This file is refered in deployment.yaml file.
I would like to store all the credentials those are mentioned in app-configmap.yaml file as environment variable into secrets in keyvault and finally from keyvault , it will be refered in app-configmap.yaml file.
I need help to understand it step by step by which I can implement it

Comment: Please refer this Document it may help you : https://medium.com/swlh/integrate-azure-key-vault-with-azure-kubernetes-service-1a8740429bea

Answer (score 0):

In general I would not recommend to use secrets as environment variables or with configmaps.

With the [AZURE KEY VAULT PROVIDER FOR SECRETS STORE CSI DRIVER](https://azure.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/configurations/sync-with-k8s-secrets/) you should use the secrets as file mounts inside the pod that really needs the secret. With this you can also [rotate secrets](https://secrets-store-csi-driver.sigs.k8s.io/topics/secret-auto-rotation.html) on-demand or [sync own TLS certs](https://azure.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/configurations/ingress-tls/) etc.

Pro is you dont need AAD-Pod-Identity bcs the [CSI](https://azure.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/configurations/identity-access-modes/) handles auth on its own.